# I am from or I come from in Chinese

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the difference of these two and are they used only for the place you originated from?

Comment: You may want to add some more details about what you mean/what you're looking for as the question is somewhat ambiguous in its current state.

Comment: It seems this question is about the English language, not Chinese. I think this is not the appropriate place for this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the Chinese language.

Answer (score 1):

Direct translation:

I (am) from -> 我從____
I am from Canada -> 我從加拿大來的
**Note**: "來的" has to be added at the end to show "從加拿大" is to describe where you came from, or else "我從加拿大" is an incomplete sentence in Mandarin.

I come from -> 我來自____
I came from Canada -> 我來自加拿大

I won't get into too much details on the usage of "從", as that seems to be a different topic from what you're asking.
As for the difference between the two, I can't think of any right now. Just like they both mean the same thing in English.